# How can i use sys.stdout.flush() on python3

Tags: python-3.x

**This is a python2 script how can i use this on python3**

```
import sys

for x in range(10000):

    print "HAPPY >> %s <<\r" % str(x),
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: Why exactly do you need to flush?

Comment: I want to use this on my script

Comment: Yes the last one thank you

Answer (score 1):

Idiomatic Python 3 would use the `end` and `flush` parameters to the [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) function, along with an [`f-string`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#tut-f-strings):

```
for x in range(10000):
    print(f"HAPPY >> {x} <<", end="\r", flush=True)
```

Comment: Ok thank you for your help